# Haskell - Make a function with one case difference from an other function

Tags: haskell

I have a question about on how to change only one case of this structure:

```
type Foo a = String -> a
--Let's define a function.
foo :: Foo Int
foo "a" = 5
foo "b" = 6
foo "c" = 7
foo x = 0
```

Now suppose I want to create another function that gives me another function
  but only changed in one case, this is what I did.

```
changeFoo :: Foo a -> String -> a -> Foo a
changeFoo = \foo -> \str -> \x -> (\str -> \x)
```

I'm new at programming Haskell and this doesn't seem to change only one case of the function. If someone can tell me what to do I'll be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your existing `changeFoo` function produces the constant function that always returns `x`. The second lambda expression that introduces the variable `str`, `(\str -> \x)`, hides the `str` variable introduced by the lambda expression `\str -> \x -> (\str -> \x)`. It might as well be `changeFoo = \foo -> \str1 -> \x -> (\str2 -> \x)`. The two `str` variables are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the strings are equal or not. Something like

```
changeFoo :: (String -> Int) -> String -> Int -> String -> Int
changeFoo f s1 a s2
    | s1 == s2 = a
    | otherwise = f s2
```

I think changeFoo can be given a more general type though:

```
changeFoo :: Eq a => (a -> b) -> a -> b -> a -> b
```

Another way to write it even more generically is with the maybe type:

```
changeFoo :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> a -> b
```

But that will clearly require a different implementation.

Comment: `changeFoo f s1 a s2
    | s1 == s2 = a
    | otherwise = f s2` in this part `f` is a function `(String -> Int)` ,  `s1` is the second parameter (Which is an String) , `a` is an Int and `s2` is the last String parameter? is that okay or am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly like that. So `s1` is the case you want to change, `a` what you want to change it into, and `s2` the argument to the function that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit overkill and only worth it if you already use the `lens` library in your project, but module [`Control.Lens.Prism`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.7/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) offers a way to define "setters" for functions that override the behaviour of the functions for particular input values.

Suppose that we want we override the behaviour for "c" in your case. We begin by defining a `Prism` for `"c"` using `only`:

```
 only "c"
 -- This Prism compares for exact equality with a given value.
```

Then we build the "`Setter` for functions" using `outside`:

```
 outside $ only "c"
```

The whole new definition:

```
 foo' :: Foo Int
 foo' = set (outside $ only "c") (\_ -> 77) foo
```

Testing it:

```
 foo' "c"
 >>> 77
```