# How to update a function to produce a different value on a certain input in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

Im reletivly new to Haskell and Im trying to get my head around highter order functions. I want to create an update function such that I can call it as follows:

```
if somefunc' = update sumfunc 42 "y", then
   somefunc' x = { 42           if x  = "y"
                   (somefunc x) if x != "y"}
```

I tried writing something like this:

```
update :: Eq a => (a->b) -> b -> a -> (a->b)
update f x y = f_new
        where   f_new :: a -> b
                f_new y = x
                f_new _ = f
```

Im aware its probably completely incorrect but If you could give me a way to do this while keeping the signature of update Ive used it would be extremely helpful. Thank you

Comment: Could you perhaps explain in words what you want update to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell - Make a function with one case difference from an other function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446662/haskell-make-a-function-with-one-case-difference-from-an-other-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pattern match on a variable and expect it to turn into some kind of equality test. A variable pattern always matches anything. If you want an equality test, use a guard.

Also, you cannot use the type signature on the where-clause as you do because the local function isn't actually polymorphic. (If you want something like that, you need the ScopedTypeVariables language extension.)

And in the final line, there's a type error, because you match on an argument but then return the function `f` rather than applying it.

All in all, your code should look more like this:

```
update :: Eq a => (a -> b) -> b -> a -> (a -> b)
update f x y = f_new
  where
    f_new z | z == y    = x
            | otherwise = f z
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpfull but im having a bit of trouble. When I use this update on a function only the latest update seems to be remembered and if the updated function is called using anything but the y value it fails (theres no error it just gets stuck till i interupt it)

Comment: Your comment sounds as if you are trying to update a function destructively as in an imperative language. You cannot do this in Haskell. You have to give the updated function a different name and both the original and the updated function coexist.